# rspec: getting failure/error while redirecting to index action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, rspec-rails, rspec3

I am new to rspec. I am getting failure message as shown below:

```
Failures:

 1) PostsController PUT update it success when update a post
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to(posts_url)
       Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200>
     # ./spec/controllers/posts_controller_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.24448 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/posts_controller_spec.rb:8 # PostsController PUT update it success when update a post
```

I have following codes in posts_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PostsController do

  describe "PUT update" do
    let(:post) {FactoryGirl.create(:post)}

    it "it success when update a post" do
      @post = FactoryGirl.create(:post, :title => "my title", :content => "my content")
      expect {put :update, :id => @post.id }
      // put :update, { :id => @post.id, :post => { "title" => "MyString", :content => "my content" } }
      expect(response).to redirect_to(posts_url)
    end
  end
end
```

I got many solutions, but did not get success.

I am getting issue in this line

```
  expect(response).to redirect_to(posts_url)
```

I tried below code as well

```
specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(posts_path) }
```

FYI I have added below codes to my spec_helper.rb

```
 RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.mock_with :rspec do |c|
    c.syntax = [:should, :expect]
  end
  config.expect_with :rspec do |c|
    c.syntax = [:should, :expect]
  end
```

Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

posts_controller.rb is something like this.

```
    class PostsController < ApplicationController
        def edit
          @post = Post.find(params[:id]
        end

        def update
         @post = Post.find(params[:id])
         if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
           redirect_to posts_path
         else
           render :action => :edit
         end
        end

        def index
          @posts = Post.all
        end

        private
         def post_params
          params.require(post).permit!
         end
    end
```

### My post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :content, :presence => true
end
```

Comment: show us `PostsController` please.

Comment: @Зелёный: I have added posts_controller, please have a look at it.

Comment: Is there any validation on `Post`? It seems it is rendering edit page instead of redirecting because the update operation was not successful.

Comment: @AmitPatel: Post model contains validation presence true for the fields.

Comment: see what is the problem as explained in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According your controller, `@post` never updated because `post_params` empty, so `update` action render `edit` template with status `200`.

Try change your `it` block to update `@post` variable(this is just example):

```
it "it success when update a post" do
  @post = FactoryGirl.create(:post, :title => "my title", :content => "my content", :id => 3)
  put :update, :id => @post.id, FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:post)
  expect(response).to redirect_to(posts_url)
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much for detailed information. It worked fine after passing updating values through params.

Comment: @sivrj my pleasure, don't forget accept answer if i help solve your problem.

Comment: Yea I accepted your answer. I updated the a line to something like this, after that it worked fine>> put :update, { :id => @post.id, :post => { "title" => "MyString", :content => "my content" } }